# /etc/systemd/logind.conf ignored, no "power button behavior" in settings, how to disable the key?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, power-management, systemd, systemd-logind

I am trying to disable this popup menu of Ubuntu which shows up when you press the physical power button of your PC. I also don't want the power button to turn off my PC, I want it to be ignored by the OS. I did that before on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 by changing my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file like that:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
# [...]
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.
 
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

I am positive I've changed some GUI settings too... and that's the problem: changes in the `logind.conf` file alone are not enough (I'm still getting the menu, even after reboot), and there is nothing related in Ubuntu/Gnome settings... "Power" category there is almost empty. This is after I did this:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

The "Power Button Behavior" setting is not showing anymore, but I also need all that disabled.

I've found that there should exist a `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn-acpi-support` file, but well, it doesn't, and I wish not to go this way as the old way was working for a year now.

I've also tried installing gconf-editor but there were almost no variables to change (depreciated?). There was also this tip:

> A different application may disable logind's handling of system power
> and sleep keys and the lid switch by taking a low-level inhibitor lock
> ("handle-power-key", "handle-suspend-key", "handle-hibernate-key",
> "handle-lid-switch", "handle-reboot-switch").

...but it's a fresh, minimal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation, and I've done it many times before, I do it after every reinstall. How can it be different?